# Solvable subgroup with index less than 5

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group that has a solvable subgroup $H$ with $[G:H] \le 4$. Show that $G$ is solvable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider the homomorphism $\phi: G \to S_4$ defined by the multiplication action of $G$ on the left cosets of $H$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal core $H_G$ of $H$ in $G$ is solvable (since it is a subgroup of solvable $H$), and note that $G/H_G\leq S_4$ with $S_4$ solvable.